# Facing issue with regex in node.js

Tags: regex, node.js, express, mongoose

I want to execute a query just like wild card search in sql.So I use regex in nodejs and mongoose.When I use hard code then its works but when I put in variable it wont work.Where is the issue.

Code with hard code

```
AlertModel.find({"alertName":{$regex: /.*RTE.*/}}).lean().exec(function (err, result) {
    if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    else
        {
          return res.status(200).send(result);
        }
});
```

But in case of using variable it wont work

```
var regFiled='/.*RTE.*/';
AlertModel.find({"alertName":{$regex:regFiled}}).lean().exec(function (err, result) {
    if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    else
        {
          return res.status(200).send(result);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a variable with a string value instead of a RegExp literal.

Change

```
var regFiled='/.*RTE.*/';
```

to

```
var regFiled=/.*RTE.*/;
```

and it should work like the hard-coded version.

Or if `regFiled` really is meant to hold a string form of the expression, you can convert it to a RegExp object with:

```
{$regex:new RegExp(regFiled)}
```